# Bing maps sdk for Android and IOS native applications

Tags: android, ios, bing-maps

I have native `Android` and `IOS` application which has google maps implementation. Now I want to change maps from google to Bing maps,I didn't found any SDKs information.

Can anyone please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Azure Maps has an Android SDK currently in preview and is working on an iOS SDK. May be an option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/about-azure-maps

Answer (score 0):

There are no official mobile SDK's.

Unfortunately, if you really want to use **Bing** maps you're going to have to use a webview to present the map. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A Bing maps SDK for Android and iOS was just announced at Build on Monday
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/sdk-native/